# Spark Streaming: How to feedback output into input

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

[image]
**Is it possible to implement the above shown scenario?**
The system starts with one key-value pair and will discover new pairs. First the number of key-value pairs will increase and then shrink across iterations.

Update: I have to shift to Flink Streaming for Iteration support. Will try with kafka though!

Comment: If this about Spark why did you use Hadoop, and Flink tags?

Comment: Hadoop removed. Flink because if it is possible with flink, I will be interested to know. I may change the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Apache Flink it is possible to define feedback edges via the `iterate` API call. The `iterate` method expects a step function which, given the an input stream, produces a feedback stream and an output stream. The former stream is fed back to the step function and the latter stream is send to down stream operators.

A simple example looks like:

```scala
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

val input = env.fromElements(1).map(x => (x, math.random))

val output = input.iterate {
  inputStream =>
    val iterationBody = inputStream.flatMap {
      randomWalk =>
        val (step, position) = randomWalk
        val direction = 2 * (math.random - 0.5)
        val bifurcate = math.random >= 0.75

        Seq(
          Some((step + 1, position + direction)),
          if (bifurcate) Some((step + 1, position - direction)) else None).flatten
    }

    val feedback = iterationBody.filter {
      randomWalk => math.abs(randomWalk._2) < 1.0
    }

    val output = iterationBody.filter {
      randomWalk => math.abs(randomWalk._2) >= 1.0
    }

    (feedback, output)
}

output.print()

// execute program
env.execute("Random Walk with Bifurcation")
```

Here we calculate a random walk where we randomly split our walk to proceed in the opposite direction. A random walk is finished iff its absolute position value is greater or equal to `1.0`.

Comment: I shifted to Flink! Flink streaming seems to be much much better than Spark!